Проблема с выгрузкой 1с в битрикс
Такая ситуация при обмене с 1с
В таблицу b_xml_tree_import_1c после 1-2 шага обмена -( /1c_exchange.php?type=catalog&mode=import&filename=import.xml&sessid=a5184b0b3abd09dd7e457680310c88f0 )
В базу данных летит дублирующаяся запись, при этом ошибок sql, php нету, обмен с 1с зависает
Также заметил что сессия норм так увеличивается
$_SESSION["BX_CML2_IMPORT"]["NS"]["element_stack"]
Решить проблему частично удалось, если в настройках обмена 1с со стороны сайта выставить Интервал одного шага в секундах: 0, но тогда вручную все ок, а вот с 1с проблемы, видать время ожидания ответа или еще что-то, не продолжает выгрузку
В обмене много свойств больше 200, разделов 190, карточек товара 5000
Версия битрис 20.5.0
Куда можно копнуть? Может какие-то настройки в php.ini сделать
Уже выставил
max_execution_time 3600
max_input_time 3600
max_input_vars 100000
memory_limit 2500M

